# Best type of pin to use when two parts are rotating relative to each other?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, machine-design, machine-elements

[Edit 1]: Added material of components.

I have a flywheel with a shaft connected to it. The shaft rotates with the flywheel, but also rotates relative to it, to give me a kind of camshaft motion if you can imagine. I don't know why type of pin is best to use here, I've only pinned things that don't move relative to each other in the past.

I have added some images to try and describe this better, as you can see, the red rod always stays in the same orientation, that requires that it rotates relative to the flywheel while still moving with it. The red rod is made of aluminum, the flywheel is also made of aluminum. The black sliding component is a plastic bearing component.

[image: State 1]

[image: State 2]

Comment: Not a centerless ground pin which most pins are, so I'm told. Lobes. Maybe just a tiny piece of shaft and not a pin? I guess it depends on the expected wear and load for if lobes matters.

Comment: The material of red part matters.

Comment: Since there's more room on the disc maybe press fit it to the red part and have it move inside a bushing in the disc. Then again, of the red part has to slide within the black part then maybe the red part is already made of a bushing material in which case maybe the pin should be press fit into the disc.

Comment: so to tag on to other comments, something from a plastic piun in a hole to a steel pin in a bronze bushing to a shaft in a roller bearing.

Comment: one of the harder stainless steels would be a common starting choice, but of course it depends on details

Comment: @EricS I added the material above. The disk and red rod are both made of Aluminum.

Comment: The pin does not matter, but the track below matters. Make it a circular track, so the rod will spin with the flywheel through the pin but maintain its orientation. The lateral position of the rod will change with the movement though.